# Стили для селекта css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я бы хотел стилизировать селект, чтобы он выглядел примерно как тут https://prnt.sc/MhHMEPRS089F, как можно применять стили к этому, посколько я пробовал, смотрел в инете, но ничего из этого не работало, кто-то писал, что стили не применяются к option, также как поставить флажки как на скриншоте возле валют? Я в стилях пробовал, не получилось.

```js
const currencyOne = document.getElementById('currency-one');
const currencyTwo = document.getElementById('currency-two');
const amountOne = document.getElementById('amount-one');
const amountTwo = document.getElementById('amount-two');
const rates = document.getElementById('rate');
const swap = document.getElementById('swap');

// Fetch exchange rates and update the dome
function converter() {
  const currency_one = currencyOne.value;
  const currency_two = currencyTwo.value;

  fetch(`https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {  
    
    data.unshift({"txt":"гривна","rate":1, cc:"UAH"})
            
      c1 = data.find(item => item.cc === currency_one);
      c2 = data.find(item => item.cc === currency_two);
      //console.log(c1,c2);
      rates.innerText =  `1 ${currency_one} = ${(1 * c1.rate / c2.rate).toFixed(4)} ${currency_two}`;
      amountTwo.value = (amountOne.value !== '') ? (amountOne.value * c1.rate / c2.rate).toFixed(2) : '';
      
    });
}

converter();

// Обработчики события
currencyOne.addEventListener('change', converter);
amountOne.addEventListener('input', converter);
currencyTwo.addEventListener('change', converter);
amountTwo.addEventListener('input', converter);

swap.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const temp = currencyOne.value;
  currencyOne.value = currencyTwo.value;
  currencyTwo.value = temp;
  converter();
});
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #5fbaa7;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.indent-right {
  display: flex; 
  width: 24px; 
  height: 24px; 
  background-image: url("https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/ServiceCurrency.svg"); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: center center; 
  background-size: contain;
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}

b {
  font-weight: var(--tw-semi);
}

.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 57px;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition-duration: 450ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  word-break: normal;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 2px 4px 0px, rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 0px 4px 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.swap-rate-container .btn-arrows {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  opacity: 0.54;
  transition: opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  position:absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


.currency {
  padding: 40px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.currency select {
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 10px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%20000002%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
  background-position: right 10px top 50%, 0, 0;
  background-size: 12px auto, 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.currency select:hover {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

.currency select:focus {
  border-color: #8dc641;;
}

select {
  outline: 0;
  border: none;
}

option[value=USD] {
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: flex; 
    width: 18px; 
    height: 15px; 
    background-image: url("https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/US.svg"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center center; 
    background-size: contain;
}

input::placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  
}
.currency input {
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 68%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.currency input:hover {
  display:block;
  line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
    /* transform: scaleX(0);  
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out; */
}

.currency input:focus {
  border-color: #8dc641;
}

.currency input:hover::after {
  transform-origin:100% 50%;
}

.select-placeholder {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
}

.swap-rate-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.rate {
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none !important;
}

@media (maz-width: 600px) {
  .currency input {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Currency Converter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="indent-right"></div>
        <b>Конвертер валют</b>
      </div>
      <div class="currency">
        <!-- <div class="select-arrow">
        <div style="display: flex;">
          <svg 
          height="24" 
          width="24" 
          version="1.1" 
          viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <g 
          fill="none" 
          fill-rule="evenodd" 
          stroke="none" 
          stroke-width="1">
          <path 
          d="M0 0h24v24H0z">
        </path>
        <path 
        d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z" 
        fill="#000">
      </path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
</div> -->
        <select id="currency-one">
          <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
          <option value="USD" selected>USD</option>       
          <svg height="24px" 
          width="24px" 
          version="1.1" 
          viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path 
            d="M12.192 10.868c-1.736-.438-2.294-.892-2.294-1.597 0-.81.772-1.373 2.065-1.373 1.362 0 1.867.631 1.913 1.56h1.69c-.054-1.28-.817-2.502-2.634-2.92V5h-1.805v1.517c-1.673.255-2.99 1.335-2.99 2.769 0 1.715 1.461 2.57 3.595 3.067 1.913.445 2.295 1.1 2.295 1.79 0 .512-.375 1.329-2.065 1.329-1.576 0-2.195-.683-2.295-1.56H8c.092 1.627 1.596 2.908 3.127 2.908v1.548h1.805v-1.53c1.498 0 2.855-1.18 2.855-2.703 0-2.109-1.859-2.822-3.595-3.267z" 
            fill="#000" 
            fill-rule="evenodd" 
            stroke="none" 
            stroke-width="1">                             
            </path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
          <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
          <option value="UAH">UAH</option>
        </select>
        <input type="number" id="amount-one" placeholder="200" />
      </div>

      <div class="swap-rate-container">
        <button class="btn" id="swap">
        <div class="btn-arrows">
        <div style="display: flex;">
          <svg
            height="24px"
            width="24px"
            version="1.1"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <g
              fill="none"
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              stroke="none"
              stroke-width="1"
            >
              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
              <path
                d="M6.99 11L3 15l3.99 4v-3H14v-2H6.99v-3zM21 9l-3.99-4v3H10v2h7.01v3L21 9z"
                fill="#000"
                fill-rule="nonzero"
              ></path>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
        <div class="rate" id="rate"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="currency">
        <select id="currency-two">
          <option value="UAH" selected>UAH</option>
          <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
          <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
          <option value="USD">USD</option>
        </select>
        <input type="number" id="amount-two" placeholder="200" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Скорее всего, только делать dropdown, а не через select

Comment: Либо попробуйте сделать что-то по этой схеме https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Comment: @HaZcker, к сожалению ничего не сработало, либо я рукожоп, либо там не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select - это элемент формы, который не поддерживает теги внутри `<option>`. Можно использовать [спецсимволы](https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/) и даже [Emoji](https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).

Я набросал небольшой пример, как это можно реализовать без сторонних библиотек:

```js
function initSelects() {
  let sels = document.querySelectorAll('.select');

  for (let sel of sels) {
    let input   = sel.querySelector('input');
    let options = sel.querySelector('.options');
    let spanv   = sel.querySelector('.value');
    let defval  = options.children[0];

    spanv.innerHTML = defval.innerHTML;
    input.value = defval.dataset.value;

    sel.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      sel.classList.toggle('open');
      let option = e.target.closest('.option');

      if (option) {
        spanv.innerHTML = option.innerHTML;
        input.value = option.dataset.value;
        input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
      }
    });
  }

  window.addEventListener('click', e => {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.select')].map(o => {
      if (e.target.closest(".select") !== o) o.classList.remove('open')
    })
  });
}


/// Тестируем onchange
let currencyOne = document.getElementById('currency-one');

currencyOne.addEventListener('change', e => {
  console.log('currency-one: ' + e.target.value);
});

initSelects();
```

```css
.select {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select:after {
  content: '\25BC';
  font-size: 80%;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.options {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: none;
  z-index: 999;
}

.select.open .options { display: block; }
.option { padding: 0.2em 0.5em; }
.option:hover { background: #eee; }

i.icon {
  background: url(https://mdbootstrap.com/img/svg/flags.png) no-repeat;
  width: 16px;
  height: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
}

i.icon.eur { background-position: 0 -1794px; }
i.icon.usd { background-position: -72px -1950px; }
i.icon.gbp { background-position: -36px -26px; }
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <span class="value">---</span>
  <div class="options">
    <div class="option" data-value="EUR"><i class="icon eur"></i> EUR &euro;</div>
    <div class="option" data-value="USD"><i class="icon usd"></i> USD &dollar;</div>
    <div class="option" data-value="GBP"><i class="icon gbp"></i> GBP &pound;</div>
  </div>
  <input id="currency-one" type="hidden">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="select">
  <span class="value">---</span>
  <div class="options">
    <div class="option" data-value="EUR"><i class="icon eur"></i> EUR &euro;</div>
    <div class="option" data-value="USD"><i class="icon usd"></i> USD &dollar;</div>
    <div class="option" data-value="GBP"><i class="icon gbp"></i> GBP &pound;</div>
  </div>
  <input id="currency-two" type="hidden">
</div>
```

Вместо select используется input. Можно подписываться на событие change, как вы это и делали. Любое число селектов на странице. Стилизуйте как хотите.

Comment: А вы знаете как сделать, чтобы треугольник вращался, при выпадении этого списка? Или это уже надо делать полностью выпадающий список?

Comment: @АндрейХотюн Именно вращался? Или переворачивался при открытии списка? И что такое «полностью выпадающий список»?

Comment: да, извини, переворачивался при открытии списка, ну полностью выпадающий список, это я имею ввиду, что выпадающий список, посколько это селект, его мало можно кастомизировать, а вот выпадающий список, это можно, поэтому я так и выразился, что полностью выпадающий список, извиняюсь за невнятность.

Comment: @АндрейХотюн `.select.open:after { content: '\25B2' }`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте по этому примеру

```js
const $dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown')

setInterval(() => {
  $dropdown.classList.toggle('opened')
}, 2000)
```

```css
.currency-select {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

.currency-select__selected {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
}

.dropdown.opened {
  max-height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.dropdown__item {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.dropdown__item:hover {
  background: silver;
}

.dropdown__item.selected {
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="currency">
  <div class="currency-select" id="currency-two">
    <div class="currency-select__selected">
      UAH
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__item selected" value="UAH">UAH</div>
      <div class="dropdown__item" value="GBP">GBP</div>
      <div class="dropdown__item" value="EUR">EUR</div>
      <div class="dropdown__item" value="USD">USD</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="number" hidden id="amount-two" placeholder="200" />
</div>
```